# Made a simple calculator but I need to add something to it

Tags: java

I made a really simple calculator for my Java assignment, but I am stuck on the part where I need to add text when the user inputs a non-number. What do I need to add to it and where do I need to add it to for it to work? I've tried multiple different ways that I searched on the internet but none of them seemed to work.

This way technically works but it always has red text that goes before and after it for some reason.

```
public class MySwitchExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char operator;
        double num1;
        double num2;
        double result;
        
    
        Scanner s= new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter operator (either +, -, * or /): ");
        operator= s.next().charAt(0);
        
        System.out.print("Enter number 1 and number 2: ");
          try {
              num1= Double.parseDouble(s.next());
              num2= Double.parseDouble(s.next());
           } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
              // Double.parseDouble has changed specs several times, so fall through
              // gracefully
              e.printStackTrace();
              System.out.print("You entered text as a number: ");
              return;
           }
      
        
                 switch (operator) {
        
                    // performs addition between numbers
                    case '+':
                        result = num1 + num2;
                        System.out.print(num1 + "+" + num2 + " = " + result);
                        break;
            
                        // performs subtraction between numbers
                    case '-':
                        result = num1 - num2;
                        System.out.print(num1 + "-" + num2 + " = " + result);
                        break;
            
                        // performs multiplication between numbers
                    case '*':
                        result = num1 * num2;
                        System.out.print(num1 + "*" + num2 + " = " + result);
                        break;
                        // performs division between numbers
                    case '/':
                        result = num1 / num2;
                        System.out.print(num1 + "/" + num2 + " = " + result);
                        break;
                        
                        
            
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Invalid operator!");
                        break;
                    
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and I got no red errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use scanner.nextDouble() to read directly a double number, instead to read a string and convert it. You have put correctly the try/catch but e.printStackTrace() show you the error in the console (delete this line).
I suggest you to put the try/catch inside a while loop, so when user inserts letters the program won't be closed but loop while both number will correct. You may do this with one simply boolean

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `e.printStackTrace()`. That method tells you where the exception was thrown and is probably the red text you're referring to.